# Relative path to subdomain

Tags: php, redirect, path

On my localhost I am running a website and on the www.website.com someone should login and redirect to info.website.com. I'm using the following path to redirect the user:

```
header("Location: /info.website.com/index.php?s=welcome");
```

I uploaded it to my live server, but now it redirects to

http://website.com/info.website.com/index.php?s=welcome

How can I solve that? Should I do something with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or something else?

Answer (score 1):

`header("Location: http://info.website.com/index.php?s=welcome");`
Note: **http://**

Comment: Thanks, but if I do that on my localhost (test environment) the redirect is not ok. So should I do a check if it is local or not?

Comment: I can't see why this wouldn't work on localhost. You can check if that works for you, though

Comment: yes, but if I do that on localhost it should not go to the live version , but the local version.

Comment: No other way than to check if it's live or dev env then.

Comment: I mean: localhost should go to header("Location: http://localhost/info.website.com/index.php?s=welcome");

Comment: If you want this to work both locally and live, you have to add the host to your windows machine while working locally, and then remove it to work live.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna emulate a real domain locally, then you should change your hosts file adding something like:
    127.0.0.1 mydomain.com

And setup a vhost listening to mydomain.com (at least apache)

Then you could just change your hosts file, when you wanna fetch from production.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include http anything when you send location headers.  They can be totally relative, like so:

```
header("Location: /index.php?s=welcome");
```

This should work on both your test and production servers

Comment: It should be a path to the subdomain, not to the same domain;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'localhost')
{
    header("Location: http://info.website.com/index.php?s=welcome");
} else
{
    // go to localhost
}
```